# Problem with display graphic

Tags: floats

I'm writing document in Latex with Texmaker. My document looks like something that:

```
\subsection{Title 1}
\qquad Some text....
\\ Some text....

Some text:
\begin{itemize}
\item item1
\item item2
\item item3
\item item4
\end{itemize}

Some text:
\begin{itemize}
\item item1
\item item2
\item item3
\item item4
\end{itemize}

Some text...

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{czynnosci_serwer.jpg}
\caption{text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{czynnosci_klient.jpg}
\caption{text}
\end{figure} 

\newpage
\subsection{Title 2}
\qquad Some text

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{klasy_serwer.jpg}
\caption{text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{klasy_klient.jpg}
\caption{text}
\end{figure}

\newpage
\subsection{Title 3}
\qquad some text
```

And the problem is that graphics are put after all text, on the last page. I don't know where is a problem. I always put image in this way and have no problem.
My header:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{mwart}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ftnxtra}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your figures float away, i.e. LaTeX positions them at places where is enough space for it. If you do not want this behaviour, remove the `figure` environment and write `\captionof{figure}{text}`. Do not forget to `\usepackage{caption}` for this to work.

Comment: Never use `[h]` that is explicitly saying the figure can not go at the top, botom or on a page on its own, so you get a warning from latex and it probably goes to end of document. use `[htp]` also do not start your sections with `\qquad`! If you want initial paragraphs indented use `\usepackage{indentfirst}` The normal LaTeX style is to suppress indentation after a heading (`\quuad` will not insert the same indentation as other paragraphs, but it would be the wrong markup even if it made the correct space)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It works! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never use `[h]` that is explicitly saying the figure can not go at the top, bottom or on a page on its own, so you get a warning from latex and it probably goes to end of document.

Use `[htp]`

Also do not start your sections with `\qquad`! If you want initial paragraphs indented use

```
\usepackage{indentfirst}
```

The normal LaTeX style is to suppress indentation after a heading (`\quuad` will not insert the same indentation as other paragraphs, but it would be the wrong markup even if it made the correct space)

Answer (score 0):

I have another problem with display graphic. I have code

```
\newpage
\subsection{Title}
Text 1
\\ Text 2:
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image1.jpg}
\caption{Caption 1} 
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image2.jpg}
\caption{Caption 2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image3.jpg}
\caption{Caption 3} 
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image4.jpg}
\caption{Caption 4}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image5.jpg}
\caption{Caption 5}
\end{figure}

Text 3
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics{image6.jpg}
\caption{Caption 6}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{image7.jpg}
\caption{Caption 7}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{image8.jpg}
\caption{Caption 8}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics{image9.jpg}
\caption{Caption 9}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{image10.jpg}
\caption{Caption 10}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{image11.jpg}
\caption{Caption 11}
\end{figure}'
```

And Text 3 is displaying after image1, not image5. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For your second question,

Latex puts figures where it think is the best fit. If you want to force a figure not to go beyond a certain point, you can use `\FloatBarrier` from the package `placeins`.

Also please try to ask 1 question per topic.

**Edit:**

Try this

```
\newpage
\subsection{Title}

\FloatBarrier 

Text 1
\\ Text 2:
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image1.jpg}
\caption{Caption 1} 
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image2.jpg}
\caption{Caption 2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image3.jpg}
\caption{Caption 3} 
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image4.jpg}
\caption{Caption 4}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image5.jpg}
\caption{Caption 5}
\end{figure}

\FloatBarrier

Text 3

\FloatBarrier

\begin{figure}
...
```

Comment: I put `\FloatBarrier` after image5 and it works. But now I have something like that: [link](http://www.tinypic.pl/leq3s80blb18). But I want this: [link](http://www.tinypic.pl/hx7tz0tksg1i).

Sorry that I wrote another question in this topic.

Comment: See my edit. Does this work?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Nothing change.

Comment: Please post a new question with a fully working MWE.